# About serializers as a mechanism for dealing with concurrency

Tags: concurrency, scheme, race-condition, sicp

#### tl;dr

Is changing the former snippet below for the latter safe?

#### Complete question

In section §3.4.2 from [SICP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_and_Interpretation_of_Computer_Programs), the following function for creating an account balance able to cope with concurrent requests is shown at page 305:

```scm
(define (make-account balance)
  (define (withdraw amount)
    (if (>= balance amount)
      (begin (set! balance (- balance amount))
             balance)
      "Insufficient funds"))
  (define (deposit amount)
    (set! balance (+ balance amount))
    balance)
  (let ((protected (make-serializer)))
    (define (dispatch m)
      (cond ((eq? m 'withdraw) (protected withdraw))
            ((eq? m 'deposit) (protected deposit))
            ((eq? m 'balance) balance)
            (else (error " Unknown request -- MAKE-ACCOUNT"
                         m))))
    dispatch))
```

where a serializer named `protected` is created via `(protected (make-serializer))` in the `let` statement, and subsequently used to create, out of `withdraw` and `deposit` two functions that do the same thing as those two, but whose executions cannot interleave.

Later, in exercise 3.42 at page 307, the following alternative version is shown, and **the question is whether the change is safe**.

```scm
(define (make-account balance)
  (define (withdraw amount)
    (if (>= balance amount)
      (begin (set! balance (- balance amount))
             balance)
      "Insufficient funds"))
  (define (deposit amount)
    (set! balance (+ balance amount))
    balance)
  (let ((protected (make-serializer)))
    (let ((protected-widthdraw (protected widthdraw)) ; these lines
          (protected-deposit (protected deposit)))    ; are added
      (define (dispatch m)
        (cond ((eq? m 'withdraw) protected-withdraw)
              ((eq? m 'deposit) protected-deposit)
              ((eq? m 'balance) balance)
              (else (error " Unknown request -- MAKE-ACCOUNT"
                           m))))
      dispatch)))
```

#### My reasoning

I would be tempted to answer that yes, the change is safe, for the following reason.

In the section **Serializing access to shared state**, page 304, I read the following (my **emphasis**)

> […] serialization creates distin­guished **sets of procedures such that only one execution of a procedure in each serialized set is permitted to happen at a time**. […]
>
> We can use serialization to control access to shared variables. For ex­ample, if we want to update a shared variable based on the previous value of that variable, we put the access to the previous value of the variable and the assignment of the new value to the variable in the same proce­dure. We then ensure that no other procedure that assigns to the variable can run concurrently with this procedure by **serializing all of these procedures with the same serializer**. […]

From this, my understanding is that given *one* serializer (i.e. *one* of the objects/entities created via `make-serializer`), all functions serialized via that *one* serializer belong to the same set, hence their operations cannot interleave with each other.

Therefore, since in the second program too, the `(make-serializer)` call is made only once (for each call to `(make-account some-balance)`), only one serializer exits in the whole program (for each…), and it goes by the name of `protected`, so all functions that serializers serializes end up in the same set, and so they can't step on each other's feet.

Is this conclusion correct?

Comment: Each account returned by `make-account` has its own serializer.

Comment: @Shawn, but isn't `(make-account)` called only once per call of `(make-account whatever)`? After all the `(let ((protected (make-serializer))) rest)` is just syntactic sugar for `((lambda (protected) rest) (make-serializer))`, so from here I'd deduce that's the case.

Comment: You mean `(make-serializer)` for `(make-account)`? Yeah, it's called once per `make-account`, so (assuming it returns a new value each time it's called), one serializer per account object.  In both versions.

Comment: @Shawn, sorry, in my previous message when I wrote `(make-account)` I really meant `(make-serializer)`. And I misread your previous comment in the first place. So my question to your original comment now is "so what are you suggesting?".

Comment: That there's not just one serializer for the whole program.

Comment: If _each account returned by `make-account` has its own serializer_ and only one account is created, how can more then one serializer exist in the whole program?

Comment: If you're only going to ever make one account object, sure, then only one serializer would be created. But the whole point of having this home grown object system to capture state and dispatch to functions that have that state in their scope thing that SICP does is to make it easy to have more than one. Overkill otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I am fairly sure that the change is safe.  In particular so long as there is exactly one serializer per account you are OK.  That remains true in the modified `make-account` procedure: the only difference is that you're not allocating a new a member of the set of procedures that the serializer manages each time you say, for instance `(account 'withdraw)`, but reusing one you made earlier: you just save a little allocation overhead, really.